# "expression expected" error

Tags: jquery, laravel

I have a page where the user can select a registration type and enter some content in the tinymce textarea to associated that content to the selected registration type.

But there is shows an error "expression expected" in the code below?

In the console shows that the error is in this part:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

        var certificate = {};
        certificate[1] = '<p>cert1<img src="../../../img/image_1532441196_7.jpeg" alt="" width="1200" height="900" /></p>';
        certificate[2] = '<p>cert2</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>vr</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>ere</p>';

        $(function () {
...
```

complete jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var certificate = {};
        @foreach($event->registrationTypes as $registrationType)
                @if(!$registrationType->certificate)
            certificate[{{ $registrationType->id }}] = '';
        @else
            certificate[{{ $registrationType->id }}] = '{!!   $registrationType->certificate->content !!}';
        @endif
        @endforeach

        $(function () {

            $('.radio').change(function () {

                var registrationTypeId = $('input[name=registrationType]:checked').val();
                $(tinymce.get('certificate_content').getBody()).html(certificate[registrationTypeId]);
            });

            tinymce.init({
                selector: 'textarea',
                plugins: 'image code link lists textcolor wordcount ' +
                '         hr pagebreak colorpicker textpattern anchor table media',
                relative_urls: true,

                file_browser_callback: function (field_name, url, type, win) {
                    // trigger file upload form
                    if (type == 'image') $('#formUpload input').click();
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: add <script src="{{ asset('js/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js')}}"></script>

Comment: Thanks but same error.

Comment: is there any single quote in the value for `$registrationType->certificate->content` ?

Comment: The $registrationType->certificate->content shows like "<p>cert1<img src="../../../img/image_1532441196_7.peg" alt="" width="1200" height="900" /></p>".

Comment: try `{{ }}` instead of `{!! !!}` and check if you are still getting the same error

Comment: And also """"
<p>cert2</p>\r\n
<p>&nbsp;</p>\r\n
<p>vr</p>\r\n
<p>&nbsp;</p>\r\n
<p>ere</p>
"""".

Comment: Yes, it appears also " Invalid or unexpected token".

Comment: you are getting problem because of \r\n maybe as the script has html on a new line without the quote

Comment: If the certificate content in db is only <p>cert1</p> for example the error dont appears but if there are two <p>cert1</p><p>cert1</p> on different lines the error appears.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176799/discussion-between-mehravish-temkar-and-john).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should help:

```
@else
certificate[{{ $registrationType->id }}] = '{!!  str_replace("\r", "", str_replace("\n", "", $registrationType->certificate->content))  !!}';
@endif
```

So that there is no HTML string on a newline in your script.